# Casting Qvector<uint8_t> to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qvector

I want to convert my uint8_t vector which corresponds to the hex values of the characters to the string. But I can not convert my vector to the string. Help please
My code:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    QVector<uint8_t> vec;
    vec.push_back(51);
    vec.push_back(32);
    vec.push_back(123);
    QString message = "";
    qDebug()<<vec.at(0);

    for(int counter=0;counter<vec.length();counter++){
        message=vec.at(counter)+ message;
    }

    qDebug()<<message;
    //w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Then what errors? Does it give the wrong results? Then what result do you get, and what did you expect? Does the program crash? Where does it crash? Please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: At the very least you forgot to initialize `counter` to 0.

Comment: Thx @Botje I forget it but the results is same unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question still obscure to me but as far as i understood you want `qDebug()` to output the numbers in hexadecimal.

So it can be done via `QByteAray`. Possible implementation :

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QVector<uint8_t> vec;
    vec.push_back(51);
    vec.push_back(32);
    vec.push_back(123);

    QByteArray data;
    std::copy( vec.begin() , vec.end() , std::back_inserter( data ) );

    qDebug() << data.toHex( ' ' );

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output is :

> 33 20 7b

Also it is possible to convert a single number to string in hexadecimal representation with [QString::number( your_value , 16 )](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number). 16 represents `base` in here.

Comment: My question was converting vector variables into ASCII characters. This code gives me a clue at least thank a lot.

Comment: @BerkantAy `qDebug() << data;` will print directly ascii equivalents of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QString::fromUtf8()` or `QString::fromLatin1()` to do the conversion at once.

Comment: Could you please implement it to the example

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QVector<uint8_t> vec;
    QString message;
    QByteArray hex;
    vec.push_back(65);
    vec.push_back(72);
    vec.push_back(73);
    vec.push_back(84);

    QByteArray data;
    std::copy( vec.begin() , vec.end() , std::back_inserter( data ) );
    hex=data.toHex();
    qDebug() << hex+ " ";
    qDebug()<<message.fromUtf8(data);
   return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help (Just need to replace std::vector to qvector) :

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
    vec.push_back(51);
    vec.push_back(32);
    vec.push_back(123);

    std::vector<char> result;

    for (auto v: vec)
    {
        char c = v;
        result.push_back(c);    
    }

    std::string s(result.begin(), result.end());
    std::cout << s;
}
```